# How to control Computer RGB LEDs in Linux

Tags: linux, motherboard, led

[[I asked this on stackoverflow first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815007/how-to-control-computer-rgb-leds-in-linux)]

Since I switched to a new AMD Ryzen system my computer lit-up.
All new hardware components seem nowadays to have such fancy(?) RGB-LEDs built in (even in memory modules, even the stock CPU-cooler from AMD).
I don't like that and want to switch all LEDs in my system off.

The BIOS settings don't offer any control over the LEDs. Only the mainboard's manufacturers utility software (all for Windows) seem to be capable of controlling that lightning in my computer case.

Is there a way to control such LEDs via Linux?

Comment: You could probably just pull all the plugs.

Comment: @Tetsujin no plugs for the native LED of the mainboard, so just left with the PSU cables I could pull...

Comment: If there is a driver and you install it (or already have it) then check `/sys/class/leds/`. Compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1244163/432690).

Comment: Oh - that's cool - I like `/sys/class/leds/`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OpenRGB](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/releases).

For faster startup you can go to settings tab and disable the devices you are not using.

Comment: Yeah - OpenRGB is what I was looking for - though when I posted my original question on stackoverflow it did not exist.

Comment: I no longer trust OpenRGB not to hurt my hardware after running into https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/issues/2367

Comment: I think Open Source software don't  get or get very minimal funding - People use the software but most of the time don't really donate and it becomes difficult to developer to maintain project.

@Olson I suspect in your case its highly possible that developer did not have access to the hardware you are using.

Answer (score 1):

> even in memory modules, even the stock CPU-cooler from AMD

Many devices simply take power and then do things. They don't necessarily have control or signal lines to be able to modify or turn off LEDs.

IF LEDs are built into devices then they might not have any control whatsoever beyond the power switch on your power supply. Just because it is in your computer doesn't mean that everything is immediately controllable.

If you don't like the lighting inside your case then you should get a case that hides the lights or move the case to somewhere else where you will not notice them.

Otherwise the careful application of violence may be your only option.

Many devices have exposed wires going to the LEDs, you may be able to cut those wires and disable them that way. See [How can I disable the LEDs on my Gammaxx 400 CPU cooler?](https://superuser.com/questions/1190561/how-can-i-disable-the-leds-on-my-gammaxx-400-cpu-cooler/1190565#1190565)

Comment: Thank you @Mokubai - I guess you are right that there are some uncontrollable leds on peripherals though I was looking for a way to accomplish in Linux what comes with vendors tools for Windows.