Find LED's device attached to motherboard?
I have one Victus 15L desktop PC, that has some LED panel attached to the front of case. In Windows I was able to control this LEDs using dedicated software, but this software is not available for Linux. I was searching for OpenRGB, but the software wasn't able to recognise and list this LED panel. I wonder how could I control it?

What model is this LED panel?

https://github.com/chiahsing/omen-light not for victus specifically, but HP so might be a good start?

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1624884/how-to-control-computer-rgb-leds-in-linux
